# Is it possible to backlight an image plane?

Tags: lighting, video

I have a footage of somebody walking towards the exit of a tunnel. I want him to walk into the bright light of the exit, so that he dissolves in the light.

Since I didn't have a strong big light to light the exit, I wanted to make it in post.

Is there also a possibility in Blender to set a spotlight behind the image plane, so that the spotlight shines through the back of the image plane respectively the video footage?

Comment: Can you check if [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308005/how-to-make-light-leak-through-a-plane-lit-by-a-spot-light/308011#308011) answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable shadows in object properties → *Visibility* → *Ray Visibility*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Crantisz, I will try it today!